# Old syntax doesn't work with es6

Tags: reactjs

I'm learning react and I came across some nice examples I'm learning from, but it seems their syntax is no longer supported by react v15

initial code:

```
NewGameButton = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return React.DOM.div({
      className: 'tic-tac-toe--new-game-button',
      children: 'New game',
      onMouseUp: this.props.onClick
    });
  }
});
```

from what I had learned, I tried to rewrite this piece of code to es6:

```
class NewGameButton extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        .. ???
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

now I'm stuck, I found out that class name module is deprecated and I have no idea how to rewrite this to make it work

thanks!

Comment: So, basically you are asking how JSX works. Have a look at the documentation: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/displaying-data.html .

Comment: no actually, I'm asking how to handle those properties like className, onMouseUp and so on, and it has been answered, but thanks

Comment: Sure, that's what I meant. How to convert those values to JSX. Reading the documentation about JSX can only beneficial if you want to use it.

Answer (score 1):

This part:

```
return (
  <div>
    .. ???
  </div>
);
```

is not ES6, it's [JSX](https://facebook.github.io/jsx/), an optional but useful addition to the React ecosystem. Unfortunately it requires an additional step to transpile the HTML-like syntax to JS.

Without JSX, but using ES6 and current version of React your code would look like this:

```
class NewGameButton extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return React.createElement( // universal createElement method
      'div',   // tag name as the first argument instead of React.DOM.div method
      {
      className: 'tic-tac-toe--new-game-button',  // props as the second argument
      onMouseUp: this.props.onClick
      },
      'New game'  // children as the rest of arguments
    );
  }
};
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/47252/

or the [stateless function](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#stateless-functions) component approach:

```
const NewGameButton = props => React.createElement('div',{
        className: 'tic-tac-toe--new-game-button',
        onMouseUp: props.onClick }, 
        'New game' );
```

http://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/47254/

If you were to use the JSX syntax (HTML-like code in JS) you'd need to add a [transpilation](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-react/) step, and the `React.createElement()` code above would be generated for you from this:

```
class NewGameButton extends React.Component {
  render() {
    <div className="tic-tac-toe--new-game-button" onClick={this.props.onClick}>
       New game
    </div>
  }
};
```

or this:

```
const NewGameButton = props => (
    <div className="tic-tac-toe--new-game-button" onClick={props.onClick}>
       New game
    </div>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would start off by going through the official React documentation https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html
They give some good examples on how to get started and how everything should be structured.

Not sure what the end goal of your code is.... but any JSX markup can be returned in render.

So something like :

```
class NewGameButton extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="button" className="tic-tac-toe--new-game-button" onClick={this.props.onClick} />
        <ChildComponent />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May be that would help

```
class NewGameButton extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="tic-tac-toe--new-game-button" onMouseUp={this.props.onClick}>
           New game
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

But i really suggest you to not use `<div>` elements as clickable areas. Use `<button>` instead, because it's more right for the semantic.